# htaccess error with query strings and rewriterule

Tags: .htaccess

I have a very annoying problem with my htaccess... This file's content on an other server were functioned flawlessly.

Now I had to move my site to other server and several conditions working, but this is not:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions Inherit
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^id=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^firm\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/firm/details?id=%1 [R=301,L]
```

So when I have an url like this: www.domain.com/firm.php?id=35 then it should redirect to this url: www.domain.com/firm/details?id=35
One small note: The new engine I'm using is smarty 3 with codeigniter framework.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: And what's the problem that you're reporting?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's the same .htaccess file that worked on the old server, the most likely reason is that the new one has a more restrictive `AllowOverrides` setting which is disabling `mod_rewrite`.